# How can I make huge numbers with only tiny numbers? I have to make 55 with 1,1,1,2,2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

The content is exactly same with the title:

> Using 1,1,1,2,2, these five numbers, I have to make 55.

I think I can make from Fibonacci's function, but I can't define this with these five numbers. (I think I can't use functions for my teacher's decete answer).
So I think I can use sigma, and sum 1 to 10 also same as 55, but I don't know how to do it. Please help me.

You can use only these five numbers, 1,1,1,2,2. If you square, you also use 2, I mean that squared numbers are also included in these  five numbers. You can use all math operations, factorial, square or even floor function.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You need to clarify specifically which operations are allowed and which ones are disallowed. Even then, this seems to be a better fit on Puzzling SE. I've seen many similar math equation puzzles on there before.

Comment: If it is cheaty and pointless you can do 11(1+2+2)

Comment: Under the assumption that you can actually combine the digits to bigger number (as Paul assumed), another solution would be $112/2-1 = 55$.

Comment: Note: posted a short time later by an unregistered user on [SE Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122743/lets-make-a-huge-number-with-only-tiny-numbers).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simply concatenate them:

> 112/2-1=55

Edit: Sorry I didn't see that this answer is already in the comments. So let me provide 1 more answer, using Fibonacci:

> $F_{11-1}=F_{10}=55$

> So $F_{11-1}+2-2=55$ or $F_{11-1}\times2\div2=55$

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use sigma, you have to reserve a one for the bottom, and so you have 1,1,2,2 to make 10

Past this point is spoilers if you still want to work it out yourself. But it is interesting and fun

——————————————————————————-

Hint:  $5 \times 2 =10$ so if you can make a five with 1, 2, 1

———- First Method (Sigma) ————-

And to make ten you can do $((2+1)! -1) \times 2 = 10$

And so then move onto the sigma function
$\sum_{x=1}^{10}x = 55$

------------------Second Method (Double Factorial)------------------------------

2. If you can use double factorial then you can do this method:

double factorial is when you wright for example '$6!!$' which is equal to the product of all numbers of the same parity of $6$ so $6!! = 6 \times 4 \times 2 = 48$

So here is the method

$(2 + 1) = 3$

$(2 + 1)! = 6$

$((2 + 1)!)!! = 48$

$((2 + 1)!)!! + (2 + 1)! = 54$

$((2 + 1)!)!! + (2 + 1)! + 1= 55$

---------------Third Method (Floor)-----------------------

This method uses the floor function

$(1 + 2)! = 6$

$((1 + 2)!)! = 720$

$\sqrt{((1 + 2)!)!} = 26.8328$

$\sqrt{((1 + 2)!)!} \times 2 = 53.67$

$\lfloor\sqrt{((1 + 2)!)!} \times 2\rfloor = 53$

$\lfloor\sqrt{((1 + 2)!)!} \times 2\rfloor + 1 + 1 = 55$

———————————-Method Four (Without Factorial)——————————————

This method only uses sine, and floor

$sin(1) = 0.01745$

$sin(1)^{1-2} = 57.297$

$\lfloor sin(1)^{1-2}\rfloor = 57$

$\lfloor sin(1)^{1-2}\rfloor  - 2  \times 1= 55$

Comment: oh,very thank you! but do you have a simplier answer without using sigmas....? our grade didnt study that and i pre-study it, so maybe...icant explain it to my friends:)

Comment: yep just added a second method incase double factorial can be used

Comment: and a third method using floor, in case you can't use double factorial